# Firefox reset variables on keypress?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I wrote a little Javascript game, which works well on Google Chrome and Opera but there is a strange bug (?) in Firefox. Looks like enter/space reset variables or I don't know.

Here is the game itself:
http://borcili.fw.hu/game/index.html

After you start the ball and break some bricks in Firefox if you press enter or space the ball stops (set the started boolean to false) and after relaunch the ball the bricks reset. By the way, if you check the code you can see there isn't any declaration for enter and space keys. Even is I totally remove any keyboar operation this bug is still there. Any solution to "fix" this or anyone know why this is happening? I couldn't found out in 2 days know, even what is happening... variable reset or roll back in the code.

My only idea is this:

```
if (started == true) 
{
    ballx += ballmovex;
    bally += ballmovey;
}

//return to the middle of the bat
else 
    ballx = batx + (batw[batc] / 2) - 1;
```

The "started" boolean decide if the ball should move or move back to the middle of the bat. In firefox if you press enter or space the ball just moving always back to the middle of the bat. But enter and space should have to do anything but looks like reset this boolean.

Comment: I understand why I have to put the proper code here but I'm not sure even is this a bug of the code or a "feature" in Firefox. And I still don't know which part of the code should be fixed because there isn't any code for enter and space keyboard but that is still do something and that is the problem... it shouldn't have to do anything :(

Comment: @Gaboros, you said `reset some variables`, maybe that means you have a rough idea of what's going on. Why not tell us what these variables are and post the code that sets or uses them?

Comment: Updated with a little code and with my only idea, but I don't know why reset that variable

Comment: That's a pretty good start. Note that you didn't post the code that *modifies* `started`, but only the code that *uses* it. However, now we know `started` becomes `false` outside of your control when the `Enter` or `Space` keys are pressed in Firefox. Is `started` a "global" variable (i.e. a member of the `window` object, as opposed to a local variable declared with `var`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one of the buttons to select a difficulty is clicked, you set them all to `visibility:hidden`.  But hidden visibility doesn't preclude something having focus, apparently, and in particular the button in question still has focus.  Hitting space or enter triggers the button's click handler, which does various things including resetting the game board.

You can test this by, after the buttons are hidden, clicking somewhere outside the canvas.  That will shift focus out of the button, and then space and enter will stop doing anything weird.  Clicking on the canvas doesn't shift focus, because the default action of that event is prevented by the script.

Comment: Brilliant idea! You are totally right. I would never thought about this.
Adding simply "document.getElementById('button1').blur();" solve the problem! :)